# /dev/zero or /dev/null for redirect?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I understand that the standard to redirect to is `/dev/null`, but why not use `/dev/zero`? Does it not have the same effect?

Another question, what do all the `1>>` `2>>` `&>>` `>>&` and whatnot mean for redirection

Answer (score 4):

Using `/dev/zero` has the same effect as `/dev/null` when redirecting output to it. There is no reason not to use it. The latter is just more commonly found in examples and thus has become more popular.

As for redirection, you should check your shell's manual. The [Bash Hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial?s%5B%5D=redirection) has a tutorial on redirection and [another reference page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection?s%5B%5D=redirection).

Basically,

- `>` redirects output to a file
- `>>` when redirecting appends to a file (or creates it when it doesn't exist), whereas `>` truncates and therefore deletes file contents
- `n>`, where `n` is the number of the file descriptor, redirects output of that descriptor to a file. Typically `1` and `2` are used, being `stdout` and `stderr`, respectively.
- `m>&n` redirects file descriptor `m`'s output to `n`, so you could combine, for example, `stdout` and `stderr`: `> /dev/null 2>&1`
- `&>` also combines `stdout` and `stderr`

Comment: Well, there is a difference. If you are redirecting the input, /dev/null gives nothing, whereas /dev/zero gives zeros.

Comment: @YtvwlD That's why I said, "when redirecting output to it". Of course they have different uses for input.

Comment: Does `>&-` /really/ have the same effect as `> /dev/null`? Perhaps I'm being too pedantic here, but from where I'm sitting they look quite different.

Comment: @RobbieMckennie You're right, it doesn't work apparently. I took that info from the Wiki but didn't check at the time.

Comment: fyi: http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/zero "All write operations to /dev/zero succeed with no other effects"